# Using Angular2 in CefSharp

Tags: angular, chromium, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I'm looking for a way to run my `Angular2` application in a `CefSharp` control and establish a communication in both directions. Let me give you two examples:

1. I have a button in my Angular app and want my CefSharp to output a message box (Only as an example). I know how to get into the javascript code, but I can't compile my AngularApp, if you add a class from the C#, because it doesn't know this.

C# code:

```
private void RegisterJsObjects()
{           
    _browser.RegisterJsObject("cefTestClass", new TestClass());
}

class TestClass
{
    public void csF(string message) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(message, "#C", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
}
```

Angular code:

```
<button (click) ="cefTestClass.csF('text')"> C# Button </button>
```

---

2. I want to call `Angular` functions from my `CefSharp` application, because they get different names after compiling, I can't get access to them.

Answer (score 10):

The registered object is bound to the window object of `javascript`. You missed out the word `window` at the invocation. You have to call it like this:

```
<button (click) ="appComponentFunction()"> C# Button </button>
```

and in your AppComponent:

```
appComponentFunction(){
    window['cefTestClass'].csF('text');
}
```

---

It is important that the methods of your registered object begins with a lower case letter, otherwise `javascript` doesn't execute them.

---

If you want to call a Angular function from c# you can register a callback in your c#-class like this:

```
private IJavascriptCallback callback;

public void registerCallback(IJavascriptCallback callback)
{
    this.callback = callback;
}
```

now you must define your callback in your Angular app (eg. in the NgOnInit in your root-component):

```
window['cefTestClass'].registerCallback(function() {
  window.alert("Hallo");
});
```

now you can call the function any time in `c#`:

```
callback.ExecuteAsync();
```

Comment: If i try to compile it, i get still this Error " Property 'window' does not exist on type 'AppComponent'"

Comment: Great Thank you its Works!

Comment: @MartinZyk updated my answer according to your second issue

Answer (score 0):

As noted here: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2990, the "RegisterJsObject" function is obsolete.

Here's the recommended replacement:

```
//Old method
browser.RegisterJsObject("bound", new BoundObject(), options: BindingOptions.DefaultBinder);

//Replaced with
CefSharpSettings.WcfEnabled = true;
browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Settings.LegacyBindingEnabled = true;
browser.JavascriptObjectRepository.Register("bound", new BoundObject(), isAsync:false, options: BindingOptions.DefaultBinder);
```

Async function also replaced in similar fashion.